# Prove that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere and $f(1)-f(0)=\int_{0}^{1} f'(x)\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> Assume $f$ is uniformly continuous, increasing and convex. Prove that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere and $f(1)-f(0)=\int_{0}^{1} f'(x)\,dx$.

I think  proving $f'(x)$ differentiable almost everywhere is easy since the function is monotone, but how can I prove the second part?

Comment: from which book are these problems from  ? @user144600

Comment: Are you familiar with Lebesgue's differentiation theorem? Without it, it's going to be difficult to get to the "almost everywhere" conclusion.

Comment: Yes, I know Lebesgue's differential theorem

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the statement:

> **Claim.** Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and convex. Then $f$ is differentiable possibly except at countably many points, and
>   $$ f(0) - f(1) = \int_{0}^{1} f'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$
>   holds in Lebesgue integral sense.

In order to prove this, the following observation is quite useful.

> **Observation.** Let $a, b, c, d \in [0, 1]$ satisfy $a < b \leq c < d$. Then
>   $$ \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} \leq \frac{f(d) - f(a)}{d - a} \leq \frac{f(d) - f(c)}{d - c}. $$

This is quite obvious from the graph, and it can be easily proved from convexity of $f$. Then an immediate consequence is that both functions $f_{+}', f_{-}' : (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ with

$$ f_{+}'(x) = \lim_{y \downarrow x} \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x}, \qquad f_{-}'(x) = \lim_{y\uparrow x} \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} $$

are well-defined. Moreover, from the observation again, we easily deduce that

1. Both $f_{+}'$ and $f_{-}'$ and non-decreasing.
2. $f_{-}'(x) \leq f_{+}'(x)$ for any $x \in (0, 1)$.
3. $f_{+}'(x) \leq \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x} \leq  f_{-}'(y)$ for any $0 < x < y < 1$.

By 1, both $f_{+}'$ and $f_{-}'$ are continuous possibly except at countably many points. By 2 and 3, if both $f_{+}'$ and $f_{-}'$ are continuous at $x \in (0, 1)$, then $f_{+}'(x) = f_{-}'(x)$ and hence $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

Moreover, by 1 again, both $f_{+}'$ and $f_{-}'$ are Riemann integrable on any $[a, b] \subset (0, 1)$. Then, if $U(\phi, \Pi)$ (resp. $L(\phi, \Pi)$) denotes the upper (resp. lower) Riemann sum of $\phi$ with respect to the partition $\Pi$, then 1-3 show that

$$L(f_{+}', \Pi) \leq f(b) - f(a) \leq U(f_{-}', \Pi) \leq U(f_{+}', \Pi), $$

and so, letting the mesh size of $\Pi$ to $0$ shows that

$$ \int_{a}^{b} f_{+}'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = f(b) - f(a) = \int_{a}^{b} f_{-}'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. \tag{*} $$

Letting $a \downarrow 0$ and $b \uparrow 0$, this shows that $f_{\pm}'$ are both improperly Riemann integrable and Lebesgue integrable on $[0, 1]$ and $\text{(*)}$ holds for $[a, b] = [0, 1]$.

Finally, since $f_{\pm}'(x) = f'(x)$ for almost every $x \in [0, 1]$, it follows that $f'$ is also Lebesgue integrable and

$$ \int_{0}^{1} f'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = f(1) - f(0) $$

holds.